# String replace method is not working

Tags: java

```
public static String capitalise(String str)
{
     if (str != null || !"".equals(str))
     {
         char chr=str.charAt(0);
         String check= Character.toString(chr);
         String check1= check.toUpperCase();
         char chr1=check1.charAt(0);
         str.replace(chr, chr1);
         return str;            
    }
    else
    {
         System.out.println("Not a valid String");
    }

    return str;
}
```

Comment: Just try to do `return str.replace(chr, chr1);`. It should work as expected.

Comment: The downvotes are probably because you haven't explained the problem/ how you output is different from what you expect.

Comment: @MatthewAdams or because the code wasn't properly marked up before `ubercooluk`'s edit

Comment: @Shashank Additionally, your if condition is incorrect, it should be an and (`&&`) statement, not an or (`||`) statement, as both `null` and `""` are invalid Strings.

Answer (score 2):

Your problem is that you are not returning the result from str.replace.
Strings are immutable

Answer (score 2):

why you don't simply use:

```
String str = "THIS IS my TEST strinG";
String my_string = str.substring(0,1).toUpperCase() + str.substring(1).toLowercase();
```

Answer (score 1):

Please make sure for String you have to assign the value

```
 str = str.replace(chr, chr1);
```

Comment: but i have to uppercase to only the 1st character of the string it happens but the it replace on every where in the string eg before replace string = adwait after replace it becomes AdwAit ..

Comment: you want to get covert string adwait to Adwait  am i right?