# uppercase 1st character the string

Tags: java

> **Possible Duplicate:**
>   [String replace method is not working](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/13133803/string-replace-method-is-not-working)

```
 public static String capitalise(String str)
    {
     if (str != null || !"".equals(str))
      {
       char chr=str.charAt(0);
       String check= Character.toString(chr);
       String check1= check.toUpperCase();
       char chr1=check1.charAt(0);
       str=str.replace(chr, chr1);
       return str;

     }
     else
     {
         System.out.println("Not a valid String");
     }
     return str;
 }
```

i want to uppercase only the first character but it capitalize the first  character  where it comes for eg before upeercase string = shashank after it becomes  ShaShank...what should i do for it .

Comment: @Jan - the question is not a duplicate but, you're right, he got an answer for this question here already.

Answer (score 2):

`str.replace(chr, chr1);` replaces *all* occurences of the char in that string. It will change all `s` to `S` in your case.

User `substring` to concatenate the upper-cased first char with the rest of the string.

---

Here's a simple solution for the additional question in your comment. It will uppercase each character after a single(!) space. You may want to enhance it to allow mulitple spaces or multiple whitechars in general.

```
public static void main(final String[] args) {

    String s = "some words";
    StringBuilder result = new StringBuilder();
    boolean capitalizeNextLetter = true;
    for (char c : s.toCharArray()) {
        if (capitalizeNextLetter) {
            result.append(Character.toUpperCase(c));
            capitalizeNextLetter = false;
        } else {
            if (c == ' ') {
                capitalizeNextLetter = true;
            }
            result.append(c);
        }
    }

    System.out.println(result.toString());

}
```

Comment: BUt how i capitalize the first character of the second string i,e if i write dhawal jain then after the capitalize it would become like this Dhawal Jain.

Answer (score 1):

How about something like:

```
public static String capitalize(String str) {
    return str.substring(0, 1).toUpperCase() + str.substring(1);
}
```

Answer (score 1):

Why not simply do following

```
str= Character.toUpperCase(str.charAt(0)) + str.substring(1)
```

Answer (score 1):

try this

```
    public static String capitalise(String str)
    {
      if (str != null || !"".equals(str))
      {
        char chr = str.charAt(0);           
        String capsString  = Character.toString(chr).toUpperCase() + str.substring(1);
        return capsString;
      }
      else
      {
        System.out.println("Not a valid String");
      }
    return str;
}
```

Answer (score 1):

In your code replace method will replace all `'s'` with `'S'`.
Because char contains `'s'`;
Try this answer

```
public static String capitalise(String str)
{
 String test = str.substring(0,1);
 test=test.toUpperCase();
 System.out.println(test);
 String new1= test+str.substring(1,str.length());       
 return new1;    
 }
```

Answer (score 0):

Use **ReplaceFirst** method.

```
str=str.replaceFirst(check, chreck1);
```

[replaceFirst](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/6/docs/api/java/lang/String.html#replaceFirst)

Also, you should change your `if` condition to following:

```
if (str != null && !"".equals(str))
```

This way empty string won't be processed.

Answer (score 0):

Try this.just change one line.

```
public static String capitalise(String str)
{
 if (str != null || !"".equals(str))
  {
   char chr=str.charAt(0);
   String check= Character.toString(chr);
   String check1= check.toUpperCase();       
   str=check1+str.substring(1);
   return str;
 }
 else
 {
     System.out.println("Not a valid String");
 }
 return str;
}
```